# Jenkins fail on installing ros-indigo-ros

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Last two mavros build on buildfarm fails, and I don't know what i must change, because it fail to instal ros-indigo-ros package!

- http://jenkins.ros.org/job/doc-indigo-mavros/16/
- http://jenkins.ros.org/job/doc-indigo-mavros/17/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/184834/jenkins-fail-on-installing-ros-indigo-ros/) by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 404 on 2014-07-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-07-06**:
Pre-release test of ros-indigo-ros also just failed http://jenkins.ros.org/job/prerelease-indigo-ros/ARCH_PARAM=amd64,UBUNTU_PARAM=trusty,label=prerelease/1/console There might be a temporary issue there..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a systematic issue at the moment. We haven't been able to track it down yet.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0